# In what cases would it be required to read/write on 0.0.0.0 IP

Tags: java, sockets, networking

What is the benefit of binding a socket to a specific port on 0.0.0.0 with REUSEADDR enabled ?

Suppose there are four processes

**A listening on 0.0.0.0 port 9999**

**B listening on 0.0.0.0 port 8888**

**C listening on 0.0.0.0 port 7777**

**d listening on 0.0.0.0 port 6666**

To read or write data both host and port need to be specified thus that read/write operation would be from only one of above the connections.
So what is the benefit over having unique IP addresses for A,B,C,D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit is if the host has more than one IP address, as they all do, 0.0.0.0 will allow the application to accept connections made via any of them. Otherwise the application would have to have a socket per IP address.

Answer (score -2):

0.0.0.0/8 - Addresses in this block refer to source hosts on "this"
network. Address 0.0.0.0/32 may be used as a source address for this
host on this network; other addresses within 0.0.0.0/8 may be used to
refer to specified hosts on this network ([RFC1122], Section 3.2.1.3).

Comment: You've got this back to front. Read the question.